# Load data infile str_to_date conversion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a csv file created by exporting a SQL Server table and I'm trying to import it into a MySQL table. Here are the first 10 lines of the export file

```
"ID","EVENT","DATE_TIME","IP_ADDRESS","USER_ID","ITEM_ID","SESSION_ID"
5742,"browse protocol",14-JUL-09 09.15.17.000000000 AM,"10.128.101.13","","1",""
5743,"browse protocol",14-JUL-09 09.31.37.000000000 AM,"74.181.121.77","","37",""
5744,"browse measure",14-JUL-09 10.34.35.000000000 AM,"99.20.254.1","","25",""
5745,"browse domain",14-JUL-09 10.39.12.000000000 AM,"65.55.104.26","","1",""
5746,"browse measure",14-JUL-09 12.45.35.000000000 PM,"75.91.11.40","","19",""
5747,"browse protocol",14-JUL-09 01.14.50.000000000 PM,"66.249.67.181","","41",""
5748,"cart add measures",14-JUL-09 02.03.20.000000000 PM,"65.55.211.12","","21,23",""
5749,"browse protocol",14-JUL-09 02.30.24.000000000 PM,"66.249.67.181","","41",""
5750,"browse domain",14-JUL-09 03.43.47.000000000 PM,"10.128.101.13","","1",""
5751,"browse measure",14-JUL-09 03.43.48.000000000 PM,"10.128.101.13","","11",""
```

The MySQL table requires the date time to be in the following format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I have the following bit of code that loads everything properly except for the date. What am I missing?

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/sh/Desktop/site_metric_test.csv' into table site_metrics
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
(id, event, @var1, ip_address, user_id, item_id, session_id)
SET date_time = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: %b - Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format?

Comment: @P.Salmon that helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have fixed the problem: `SET date_time = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')`

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/sh/Desktop/export_head.csv' into table site_metrics
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
(id, event, @var1, ip_address, user_id, item_id, session_id)
SET date_time = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```